# SBS 2008 Email Distrubition Groups - Permissions

Tags: email, windows-sbs

is it possible to limit the email addresses that use an Email Distribution Email group?

For example:

Person A - Send emails to Group B saying the office is closed due to bad weather.

Group B: Recieves Email

Person B from Group B: Decides to try & email Group B

Ideally we would like to limit the ability to send email to a distribution group, to a certain email address.

Is this possible?

**Small Business Server 2008, with Exchange 2007**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to @kaerast.

Simply follow their guide, however, the Exchange general tab, in Exchange 2007 has been renamed "Mail Flow Settings"

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.exchangefaq.org/faq/Exchange-2003/Transport/q/How-do-you-restrict-Distribution-Lists?/qid/1084

To set restrictions on a distribution list

1. Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Exchange, and then click Active Directory Users and Computers.
2. Expand your organizational unit container, and double-click Users.
3. Right-click the distribution list for which you want to restrict submissions, and then click Properties.
4. Click the Exchange General tab.
5. Under Message Restrictions, under Accept messages, select one of the following options:

   - Click From everyone to allow anyone to send to this distribution list. This includes anonymous users from the Internet.
   - Click From authenticated users only to allow only authenticated users to send mail to this distribution list.
   - Click Only from to specify a select set of users or groups that can send to this group and then click Add to specify the users or groups that you want to permit to send mail to this distribution list.
   - Click From everyone except to allow everyone but a select set of users or groups to send to this distribution group and then click Add to specify the list of users or groups that you want to restrict from sending to this distribution list.

Comment: Thanks for the guide, however SBS 2008 has Exchange 2007 embedded, so this guide is a little out of date and I don't seem to b eable to find the Exchange tab, or Message Restrictions tab